# Remove elements from string after list of characters- without using a foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have a string that may contain some forbidden characters like let's say :

```
char[] BAD_CHARS = new char[] { '-', '.' };
```

I want  strings like "Foo 106.4" to be represented like "Foo 106"

```
fooString= fooString.Substring(0, fooString.LastIndexOf('-'));
```

This would be the solution  ... but im looking for something more dynamic .

How can I apply this logic above to the BAD_CHARS without doing foreach loops ?

Comment: without doing foreach loops ? Use for loop instead.

Comment: I asking for an alternate solution. If you dont know one ... hope others will and we both can learn from my question

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Can you remove the duplicate tag ? It is clearly a different solution to a different question than the one you tagged

Comment: Sure, I'll remove if it is different. Isn't that you're asking for? or you don't need characters after `bad character` ?

Comment: I need all characters before the occurence; and that occurence should be from a list of special characters. And I need that solution to be implemented faster than a foreach loop. The result provided by @DatRid does that . I am a positive memeber of this community and I've only asked questions that are unique ( have done my SO research before asking this )

Comment: No offense, You'll see myself also as a positive member here. We're here to help people. and *without doing foreach loops* criteria bugs me, do you think you can do it without loops? btw split internally uses loops(something to be aware of).

Comment: I want my code to be as efficient as possible. Its the main reason why I use this site. I used the foreach explanation because other solutions used that( including the one you linked this Question to) 
The second answer to this question is even better than the first one. I keep learning stuff everyday :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close. Assuming you want to stop at the *first* (not *last*) bad character,

```
fooString = fooString.Substring(0, fooString.IndexOfAny(BAD_CHARS));
```

This has the advantage of not having to process (and split into substrings) the *entire input*.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and should be the marked answer to my question

Answer (score 3):

You could do it that way with [string.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

```
string foostring = "foo 204.5-4";
string[] splitted = foostring.Split(BAD_CHARS);
string result = splitted[0];
```

Or

```
string foostring = "foo 204.5-4";
string result = foostring.Split(BAD_CHARS)[0];
```

You can try it out [here](http://rextester.com/JIUC68535)

Comment: Sure ... had to wait a couple of minutes before I could